# schedule selector in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, ios

I have encountered a problem in my app that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions was taking too long to finish, what could possibly result in the app being terminated.

I have also been getting crash reports from itunes connect that seem to indicate that the app takes too long to launch.

This might be caused by the fact that I was loading some textures synchronously during didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, a process that takes more than a second.

In an attempt to solve it, I call the method that loads the data after delay, in the following way:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(loadTextures) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
```

The way I understand - though I might be wrong - the scheduled task will not be carried out on a different thread, and therefore will only be processed after didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is done.

**My question is:**
Are there any best practice solutions for such a problem? Is the solution I suggested works as I intended?

Also, is apple's watchdog known to check apps for responsiveness even after the launch phase in cases such as this?

Comment: are you importing data from internet in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ?

Comment: I use several well-known 3rd party sdks (Flurry, BugSense, ChartBoost), so the answer is yes, though all internet calls are async.

Comment: Are you loading textures for an OpenGL application? I yes, I would suggest, you move your code to loading on a background thread. This should be a good starting point: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1612/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem in our ebook reader application where we copy ebooks (of several MBs) from bundle to the documents directory.Scheduling selector for copying the books has been the best solution so far.The same solution works fine in your case as well.I am not sure about apple's watch dog but our application is live on the app store and running since more then one year with this solution incorporated.